# How do I write a test class for trigger below, can't seem to get it

Tags: unit-test

```
trigger PostCustTrip on New_Trip_Reports__c (after update) {

  For (New_Trip_Reports__c ntr :Trigger.new){

    If (ntr.SubmitStatusCust__c == true){

      FeedItem post = new FeedItem();

      post.ParentId = '0F9K00000000Fb0';

      post.Body = ntr.CustomerName__c;

      post.title = 'Click here to view Customer Trip Report';

      post.LinkUrl = 'https://kapcoglobal.my.salesforce.com/' + ntr.LinktotheRecord__c;  
      insert post; 

     }
   }  
}
```

Added from comment:

```
 @isTest Private class TestNew_Trip_Reports {  
      Static testMethod void testNew_Trip_Reports() {  
        New_Trip_Reports__c ntr = new New_Trip_Reports__c ();
        FeedItem post = new FeedItem();  
        post.ParentId = '0F9K00000000Fb0';
        post.body = 'close';  
        post.title = 'TextPost';
        insert post;
      }
}
```

Comment: Can you add to your question what you have so far for your test and where you are getting stuck? Also noticed that you have an insert inside of your for loop which you do not want to do, you need to bulkify your trigger.

Comment: @isTest
Private class TestNew_Trip_Reports {

Static testMethod void testNew_Trip_Reports() {
       
      New_Trip_Reports__c ntr = new New_Trip_Reports__c ();


FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
post.ParentId = '0F9K00000000Fb0';
post.body = 'close';
post.title = 'TextPost';
insert post;

        
    }

}

Comment: Not sure if I'm even doing it right.

Comment: Also, your trigger executes `after update` but you don't ever update your New_Trip_Reports__c record in your test after inserting it.

Comment: Not sure you want to hard code an Id in your trigger either. Have you taken a look at process builder to see if you can add a post that way vs. a trigger?

Comment: best practice: query a custom setting or the like for the ID to use in `post.parentId=...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@isTest Private class TestNew_Trip_Reports {  
      Static testMethod void testNew_Trip_Reports() {  
        New_Trip_Reports__c ntr = new New_Trip_Reports__c ();
        ntr.CustomerName__c = 'Test';

        insert ntr;

        Test.startTest();
        ntr.SubmitStatusCust__c = true;
        update ntr;
        Test.stopTest();

        System.AssertEquals(database.countquery('SELECT COUNT() FROM FeedItemPost), 1);
      }
}
```

Also, Salesforce best practices recommend to not make insert or update in a for loop. So here's a modification of your trigger:

```
trigger PostCustTrip on New_Trip_Reports__c (after update) {

  List<FeedItem> postsToInsert = new List<FeedItem>();

  For (New_Trip_Reports__c ntr :Trigger.new){

    If (ntr.SubmitStatusCust__c == true){

      FeedItem post = new FeedItem();

      post.ParentId = '0F9K00000000Fb0';

      post.Body = ntr.CustomerName__c;

      post.title = 'Click here to view Customer Trip Report';

      post.LinkUrl = 'https://kapcoglobal.my.salesforce.com/' + ntr.LinktotheRecord__c;  

      postsToInsert.add(post);    
     }
   }  

   insert postsToInsert;
}
```

Comment: Two things, though: (1) System.assert* methods take the *expected* value first, so it should be `System.assertEquals(1, ...);`, and (2) You can use inline queries normally with COUNT(), so you can write this: `System.assertEquals(1, [SELECT COUNT() FROM FeedItemPost]);`.